# Installing packages in Python 3.8 - pip fatal error, seems to be stuck on 3.6 somehow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am running Python 3.8.3. Previously I had Python 3.6 installed.

When I try to install by pip e.g.

`pip install requests`

I get the error

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe" install requests'`

Uninstalling Python 3.6 did not resolve this. I also tried reinstalling pip from `https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files`.

How can I get pip working again so I can install packages again?

On a side note, the reason I installed 3.8.3 in the first place instead of continuing with 3.6 was that Windows opened its app store any time the `python` command was used in PowerShell. I figured I might as well download the new version, since at the time I saw no reason to fight it. Still, it would be nice to know how to stop Windows from commandeering this.

Comment: when you type python into your command prompt what version does it say it is?

Comment: 3.8.3. That's how I checked the version number, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If typing python in your command prompt opens python 3.6 then try py -3 or another possible PATH variable you have set for python 3.8

then to use pip for just that python version do the following command

```
[PATH VARIABLE] -m pip install [py-package]
```

e.g.

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Comment: Thank you, `python -m pip install requests` worked!
Typing `python` in my command prompt opens 3.8; if I uninstall 3.8, instead `python` opens the Windows store on the page for downloading Python 3.8.

Comment: @BGreen be sure to also clear out Your environment variables and set a new one for the pip that is associated with new version of python if You would like to use the `pip install` instead of `python -m pip install`

Comment: @Kaszanas How would I do that? Sorry, I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: @BGreen I think that this link will explain on how to check if You don't have anything that You do not want inside Your Environment Variables: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
e.g. if You have python set up inside Your PATH this will allow You to use `python -m pip install` because system looks for `python` inside PATH variables that You set.

Answer (score 1):

When you are runing `pip install requests`, it runs the first `pip` it finds on th path. You can see from the error message, that it is using `c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe`, so you are not really installing anything for Python 3.8.

If running `python` on your computer runs Python 3.8, then I suggest using this option to run pip:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

And if you have to enter full path to start python3.8, than do that:

```
/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install requests
```